# What is the best practice to deploy local contracts for testing?

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I am trying to developing smart contracts let use some Tokens and DeFi protocols like USDC, Compound, Uniswap, etc. Then if I need to testing locally, I need to deploy them in localhost blockchain (Ganache). I currently can't find a good way to do this. Please help.

Comment: [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/overview).